# Check is there is an Empty Column Value

Tags: mysql

Let's say we have a Table in MySQL Database called `TAB1` that Contains two Columns `col1 : col2` .
the question is :
is there a way to check is any of these Columns Contain a Null or Empty Value?
for the Condition `WHERE col_Name is null OR col_Name=''` , this Query checks one Column, I want to check all the Columns using a simple Query.

Comment: Sorry, spell out all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ISNULL` and `NULLIF` for this purpose:

```
SELECT * FROM `TAB1` WHERE ISNULL(col1, '') = '' OR ISNULL(col2, '') = ''
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `TAB1` WHERE NULLIF(col1, '') IS NULL OR NULLIF(col2, '') IS NULL
```